Binomial distribution in reliability theory
Do binomial distributions $Bin(n,p)$ always have increasing hazard rate?

If the sample size reduces with each failure, does the hazard rate, by definition, increase? (It seems obvious, so maybe I am missing something here - can you clarify the question?)

The hazard rate is defined as $\mathbb{P}(X=k)/\mathbb{P}(X\geq k)$. For $X$ binomial I find it very difficult to show that it is an increasing function, for all $n$ and $p$, so maybe it is not?

@RedFive My intuition is exactly as you say, but it is informal. I think it should be shown analytically though, if it is true.

Empirically it seems true, increasing from $(1-p)^n$ (when $k=0$) to $1$ (when $k=n$).  For $k < np$, the numerator is increasing while the denominator is decreasing.

Again empirically, if $h(k) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=k)}{\mathbb{P}(X\geq k)}$, it seems you can say $h(k) \ge \left(1+\frac{p}{n(1-p)}\right) h(k-1)$ for $1 \le k \le n$ and $0 \lt p \lt 1$, which would imply $h(k)$ is increasing.
